# How to load csv with datetime into postgresql using copy_from

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to find a way to bulk load a csv file into postgresql. However, the data has datetime column with the format of "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS". I couldn't find any documentation on how to bulk load date column using psycopg2 package in python 3.x. Can I get some help on this? Thanks in advance.

I am able to load the data using the below code:

`cur.copy_from(dataIterator,'cmodm.patient_visit',sep=chr(31),size=8192,null='') conn.commit()`

However, only the date part got loaded in the table. The time part was initialized:

`2017-04-13 00:00:00 2017-04-13 00:00:00 2017-04-12 00:00:00`

Comment: That format should not be a problem. Have you tried to load the data? If it did not work what was the error? For `psycopg2` see [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#copy).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I am able to load the data using the below code:

cur.copy_from(dataIterator,'cmodm.patient_visit',sep=chr(31),size=8192,null='')
conn.commit()

However, only the date part got loaded in the table. The time part was initialized:

2017-04-13 00:00:00
2017-04-13 00:00:00
2017-04-12 00:00:00

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the data type for the column you  are putting the datetime in is `date` not `timestamp`. That would truncate the datetime to a date only.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thanks for your response, I am using timestamp type for the date column dispensed_date:
CREATE TABLE cmodm.patient_visit (
 pat_visit_sk int4 NULL,
 patient_visit_rx_id numeric NULL,
 patient_visit_id numeric NULL,
 rx_number varchar(50) NULL,
 description varchar(255) NULL,
 dispensed_date timestamp NULL);

Comment: Have you checked the CSV to make sure it actually contained timestamps and not just dates?

Comment: @Belayer, you pointed me in the right direction. Most of the data in source didn't have time. However, for some of the rows, time part was present and was duly updated in the target table.
Say, if the format of the date in source is different (like MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS), then how will the copy_from behave? How can I tell it about the format of the date columns?

Comment: I have a basic rule: Never load a CSV into the destination table, always load to a staging table, even when an automated loads to the destination table directly and immediatly. I just do not trust the data content in spreadsheets as literately any junk can be thrown into any column. The staging table defines everything as text. I can validate and correct if necessary. In this case I would load to a staging table then edit/validate to the desired format. Then load into the final table knowing the data is valid.

Comment: @Belayer, I have to build a process to copy ~400 tables for operational data source. I don't think it'd be a good idea to use staging table.

Comment: @AnandRajakrishnan, Well I guess we have to disagree, The more data you gather, especially from spreadsheets,  the greater your chance of incomplete, poorly structured relational data, or inaccurate data you have. As I indicated you can stage and load in single process. Just takes longer, but still capture/reprocess/correct invalid data before it hits your production system. Much more difficult to do when you load directly. I consider ensuring data quality and accuracy to be by far the more mportant component of a data base process.  Missing data is bad. Bad data is worse.

Comment: @Belayer, I don't think there is any disagreement in keeping the veracity of the loaded data. What I don't agree is on the use of staging table. My source is csv file from external DB. I should be able to load it without adding staging table. If there is no way to configure copy_from method for different types of date formats, then i'll have to add a step in my code to transform all date type string into the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'. If copy_from has that capability, then it'll make my task simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately copy_from does not have that capability,  at least AFAIK. It can have ant *single format*, but not dynamic determination. Perhaps you could define the other db(s) as foreign tables. As far as an external db as you source obviously it is not consistent. Perhaps you can identify the format from the file name and provide different versions on the copy.  I think it is time to end as this is becoming a discussion which is inappropriate for SO. We could continue in chat, but I'll be away for the next couple days.

Comment: @Belayer, I think I got my answer from our discussion. I'll funnel the date to copy_from after converting the date string to the format consumable by it. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with @Belayer, it was concluded that copy_from takes the timestamp input value in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'. If the source has some other format, then that needs to be converted to the desired format mentioned before in this response before feeding it into copy_from.